# UITableView with TextField and moving the view when keypad comes up

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, uitextfield

I have a UITableView that contains text field in each row. The text field is allowed to take only numbers and decimals. I have a transparent background button to help users click on the view to dispose the keypad when it is up. The text fields at the bottom of the view are getting covered by the keypad, so I wanted to move the view by capturing the textDidBeginEditing method etc and animating the view upward. The problem I notice is that after this code to move the view was added, if the numeric keypad is up and if I click on the view outside the keypad to dispose it, the background button does not receive the event so the keypad is not disposed. Can this be fixed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the button does not cover the entire view. For your convenience you can make the button non-transparent and have some image on it to see its size.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the button is on the top of the view layer order.
Also confirm the button is there on the view after the view animation.